# ASP NET MVC partial view rendering without postback request form view to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using ASP NET MVC4, I want to use partial view to update my main view. On the server I get certain events from another server, and when that happens I want to update the partial view and post it to the client.  How can I do that? In other words, I want a way to force rendering partial view on the server side without a postback request coming from the client. Is that possible, or the client must be informed first and then does its own postback action to trigger the partial view rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Call The follwing Ajax call on every other server event or call it periodically

```
$.get('@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")', function (data) {
                $('#Id of div where Partial View is renderred').html(data);
});
```

In the action called.

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
         //load your model with changes

         return PartialView("Name of your partial view", model);

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, $.get('@Url.Action... is invoked by the client to trigger server rendering. This means that the client has to know when to invoke this, but only the server knows when the partial view is needed (because it receives some events from another server which indictates the need for showing view update). Calling it periodically or every other server event will lead to frequent reloading of the view. Could you please clarify if I understood what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for late reply yes what you understood is correct. yes it will create unnecessary reloading of view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better job for SignalR for large scale Real-time work reference:

[http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server][1]

Or if you just need to stay on single medium, you can look into node.js, which is Server side javascript and allows for binding of js function to server driven events (i.e. Client independent)

One last thought would be to use  events and kick out Web Api Responses, but that would be getting  a lot of weight on JSON without page requests.